# Error after installing search service application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

I got this this error after setting up Search Service Application with Powershell.

> The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the
>   administration component. Verify that the administration component   
>   'a23fd668-f823- 4ab2-b0fc-b0baebfd4af2' in search application
>   'SharePoint_Search_Service' is in a good state and try again.

The Sharepoint Search Service was showing error when I visited

Central Administration->Application Management->Service Applications->
    Manage Service Applications

Here is the powershell script used

```
$App1 = "APP-Server-01"
$APP2 = "APP-Server-02"
$SearchAppPoolName = "SharePoint_SearchApp"
$SearchAppPoolAccountName = "EXSERV\Administrator"
$SearchServiceName = "SharePoint_Search_Service"
$SearchServiceProxyName = "SharePoint_Search_Proxy"
$DatabaseName = "SharePoint_Search_AdminDB"
```

## Create a Search Service Application Pool

```
$spAppPool = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name $SearchAppPoolName -Account    
$SearchAppPoolAccountName -Verbose
```

## Start Search Service Instance on all Application Servers

```
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance $App1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance $App2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceInstance $App1 -ErrorAction  
      SilentlyContinue
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceInstance $App2 -ErrorAction 
      SilentlyContinue
```

## Create Search Service Application

```
$ServiceApplication = New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Partitioned -Name   
    $SearchServiceName -ApplicationPool $spAppPool.Name -DatabaseName $DatabaseName
```

## Create Search Service Proxy

```
New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy -Partitioned -Name  
    $SearchServiceProxyName -SearchApplication $ServiceApplication
```

Comment: Can you please post the powershell script you tried with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually discovered the reason for the errors, you need a domain account not a local account to create a search service application. Use an active directory created domain account to create the service appplication.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solutions

1. Application Pool account don't have enough permission to access. Try changing the application pool to use `SharePoint Web Services System`
2. Enable the timer job and RESET IIS

   - `Get-SPTimerJob job-application-server-admin-service`
   - `Enable-SPTimerJob job-application-server-admin-service`
   - `Net Stop sptimerv4`
   - `Net Start sptimerv4`
   - iisreset
3. Ensure the account has full permission son the search service application.

Check this http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.com/2014/07/the-search-service-is-not-able-to_19.html

[Search Service Application error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105416/search-service-application-error)

Comment: tried it, not working

Comment: let me mention also that I got an error while installing , Is there a way I can delete the installed search service application so as to try  and install it again

Comment: I also got this error "Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running."