# Search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component

Tags: 2010, search, enterprise-search

For a couple of days, I have with a problem related with **Search Service Application**. Service suddenly stopped working, being in the stopped state and did not response. I recreated the Shared Service Application, but do not work.

Error:

> **"The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component."**

Using PowerShell

```
cmdl get-spenterprisesearchserviceinstance -local
TypeName: SharePoint Server Search
Description: Index content and serve search queries
Id: {GUID}
Server: SPSERVER Name={Server Name}
Service: SearchService Name=OSearch14
Role: None
QueryComponents: {GUID}
CrawlComponents: {GUID}
AdminComponents: ()
Status: Online
```

SharePoint version: 2010

Any ideas?

I checked the below questions, and no solution... same error

- [The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169793/the-search-service-is-not-able-to-connect-to-the-machine-that-hosts-the-administ)
- [Error after installing search service application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128741/error-after-installing-search-service-application)

Comment: check also https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169793/the-search-service-is-not-able-to-connect-to-the-machine-that-hosts-the-administ

Comment: Hi Qassas, thanks for your response. I did it and no solution... same error.

Comment: Okay, let me edit and reopen your question again :), hope to find correct answer!